# PHP and trigonometry, obtain angle in degree

Tags: php

I have a rectangle triangle with measures 3, 4, 5 (3² + 4² = 25 = 5²) and I want to calculate angle in degrees, so I have `cosÂ = 3/5` and to calculate my angle, I just apply PHP `acos` function :

```
echo acos(3/5); // 0.92729521800161
```

but the value in degree is 53.13°.

`acos` function expects its argument to be exprimed in radians not in a ratio so how can find my angle in degrees with PHP please ?

Comment: Why not just multiply that by 180/pi?

Answer (score 3):

You can either multiply by 180/pi or use the [`rad2deg()`](http://php.net/rad2deg) method:

```
echo rad2deg(acos(3/5));
```

[Sample output](https://ideone.com/0NpSC3).

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are getting is in radians.

To [convert the value from radians to degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees) just multiply that by `180` and divide by `PI`.

```
echo ((acos(3/5) * 180) / M_PI); // ~53.13
```